# Distance in n-dimensional space

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have a 5x100 matrix where each row represent a certain point and each column is the coordinates of that point in the 5 dimensional space. Meaning there is actually a 100 points in total.

How can I calculate a distances between each and every point in order to find 5 points that are closest to each other?

I have done that for 2 dimensional space

```
dist=sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,o(1,:),o(1,:)').^2+bsxfun(@minus,o(2,:),o(2,:)').^2)
sorted=sort(dist,1, 'ascend')
fin=sorted(1:5,:)
summ=sum(fin)
[M,I]=min(summ)
sol=dist(:,I)
[Bsort Bidx]=getNElements(sol,5)
oTemp=o(:,[Bidx])
```

but when it comes to multidiensional problem I can't find an effective solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic, but an 5x100 matrix has 5 rows and 100 columns, so either you mean a 100x5 matrix or that each column represents a point in 5 dimensions (and that there are 100 thereof) or that each row represent a point in 100 dimensions (and there are 5 thereof).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you are right. I'm using 100x5 matrix and then transposing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,reshape(m,100,1,5),reshape(m,1,100,5)).^2,3))` should do it if the matrix is called `m` and an 100x5 matrix of 100 points in 5 dimensions.

And if you are in MATLAB R2016b or later you can even use: `sqrt(sum((reshape(m',100,1,5)-reshape(m',1,100,5)).^2,3))`.

Comment: This may of course be problematic in high dimensional cases, since it generates an `p x p x d` matrix (`p` is the number of points and `d` is the dimension) as part of the calculation - this may take up a lot of memory! If this is a problem you can always use a for loop!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using Matlab 2014, and your solution is working. By the way, do you have an experience in working with CVX? I have 2 5-dimensional datasets from which I need to choose 5 points from to enclose it in an ellipsis. What can cause a problem that CVX can solve one dataset, but fail to solve the other one?

Comment: Sorry! I have no experience with CVX.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the Euclidean distance between each point. There is a built in MATLAB function called `pdist` that should do exactly what you need. By deafult it takes a matrix `M`, with observations corresponding to rows and variables corresponding to columns, so for your purpose you should transpose your input matrix.

```
M = rand(5,100);
D = pdist(M','euclidean');
```

The output D will be a vector. If you want the (symmetric) matrix form, you can use `squareform`:

```
Dmat = squareform(D);
```

So that `Dmat(i,j)` will be the euclidean distance between point `M(:,i)` and `M(:,j)`.

Then, to find the 5 smallest elements you can sort the linear representation of `Dmat`, take the first 5 indices, and then use `ind2sub` to get the `i`s and `j`s you are looking for:

```
[~, ind] = sort(Dmat(:), 'descend');
ind = ind(1:5);
[r, c] = ind2sub(size(Dmat), ind);
```